# Using Angular Msal in integrated .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, angular, azure, single-page-application

Currently, I am working on an application where the Angular build is integrated with the .NET application. I use Azure AD authentication from the Angular app (Angular msal) to the web server.

**Locate static web app**

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
```

**Use spa:**

```
 app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

**Error**

```
AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type.
```

Before I started integrating, the two applications existed as stand alones and the authentication worked perfectly. But due to the integration, the SPA now runs as a static app with .NET as the host.

Now I suspect that the SPA is no longer recognized as SPA, but simply as a .NET application, so my authentication no longer works.

I've been using the standard guide to integrate my SPA, and the code seems to work as expected. Only the authentication doesn't work, because I don't think my return url from app registrations leads to a SPA.

Are there any solutions for this? I can imagine that the authentication should now work from the .NET hosted side, but if I do that I may be able to throw away all my msal implementation. I'm not waiting for that.

NOTE:
The application no longer runs on the default Angular port: 4200, but on a port defined in launch settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Be sure that there is no 'Origin" header sent to the server when exchanging a code for a token.

Comment: Please refer [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315313/azure-app-registration-causing-the-following-error.html) and [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/issues/37) for more details.

Comment: @Giovanni - Did you find any solution to this issue? I am also having the same problem.

Comment: @CSS No, I ended up splitting up the applications. It worked better for me atleast